# When a faces message is added during validation error, will JSF skip the invoke application phase?

Tags: validation, jsf, lifecycle, message

I need your help to understand this better. This is my case. I have a custom validator for each of my input controls in the form. So when there is any validation error,I add a corresponding FacesMessage in the validate method. My understanding was that when there is any validation error - or when there are any FacesMessages added in the validate method of the Custom Validator, it would skip the INVOKE APPLICATION phase and would directly call the RENDER RESPONSE PHASE - showing the FacesMessage that was added in the PROCESS VALIDATION Phase - Is this correct?

The problem I'm facing is - I add a FacesMessage in the PROCESS VALIDATION Phase - because of a validation error - and I add a confirmation message for the action that was taken by the user in the INVOKE APPLICATION PHASE - Now both are shown in the page in the RENDER RESPONSE Phase ? - If my understanding is correct in the above question - is it the best practice to conditionally add a confirmation FacesMessage after confirming that there are no FacesMessages in the currect FacesContext ?

This is how the message is added :

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,Constants.invalidMessageDetail,null);
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
```

This is how it is shown:

```
<h:messages errorClass="ErrorMsg" warnClass="WarningMsg" infoClass="InfoMsg" layout="table"  />
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *My understanding was that when there is any validation error - or when there are any FacesMessages added in the validate method of the Custom Validator, it would skip the INVOKE APPLICATION phase and would directly call the RENDER RESPONSE PHASE - showing the FacesMessage that was added in the PROCESS VALIDATION Phase - Is this correct?*

Partly true. It will only skip the update model values and invoke application phases when a `ValidatorException` is been **thrown**, not when simply a `FacesMessage` is been added to the `FacesContext`.

> *If my understanding is correct in the above question - is it the best practice to conditionally add a confirmation FacesMessage after confirming that there are no FacesMessages in the currect FacesContext ?*

You need to throw the `ValidatorException` as follows:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value does not meet conditions) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("value does not meet conditions"));
    }
}
```

Then it will skip the update model values and invoke application phases as desired. Please note that you don't need to manually add the faces message to the context. JSF will do it all by itself when it has caught a `ValidatorException`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. That was really helpful. But now , the messages are shown twice in the page. My sysouts in the validate method shows that the message is added only once.Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Maybe because you instructed the view side twice to show it? I.e. you have two `h:messages` elements. Hard to tell based on the as far given information.

Comment: I have added the code for How i add and how i show. Can you please check?

Comment: You are indeed explicitly adding two messages to the context yourself. Get rid of the `context.addMessage(null, facesMessage)` line, this is not the way you want to add a message during a validator exception. Just `throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage)` is enough.

Comment: your right. Thanks. I wonder How did you learn this?!!! coz the API doesn't say that throwing a ValidatorException adds the corresponding FacesMessage in the FacesContext.

Comment: Maybe because the book didn't mention at all that I have to manually add the FacesMessage to the context. It makes also sense after all. You're already passing the FacesMessage through the ValidatorException.